# C# lambda interface assignment

Tags: c#, lambda

I am attempting to compile the source code for an open source project and I am trying to understand the following code:

```
public interface INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public interface INameValue: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Value { get; set; }

}

bool ExistingHeaders(INameValue value) => 
       value.Name.Equals(jsonHeader.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) 
    && value.Value.Equals(jsonHeader.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

jsonHeader also implements INameValue

From my understanding this would attempt to create "value" as an object which implements the INameValue interface and then compare its "Name" and "Value" properties to the corresponding values in jsonHeader.

Surely instantiating an instance of an interface in this manner would result in null Name and Value properties?

Is my understanding of this correct?

Comment: Where exactly is `ExistingHeaders` declared? This is no lambda, but an expression bodied method. It doesn't create anything, it's a method that takes a `INameValue` as parameter and checks if this value's `Name` equals `jsonHeader.Name` and its `Value` equals `hsonHeader.Value`.

Comment: Nothing is creating `value` in the code you shared. They declared a method that takes as a parameter an instance of a class that implements `INameValue`. You can't instantiate an instance of an interface. There's no such thing as an instance of an interface. You can create an instance of a class which *implements* the interface.

Comment: perhaps the question is about the => ?  It is an expression bodied method introduced in c# 6 I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This...

```
bool ExistingHeaders(INameValue value) => 
       value.Name.Equals(jsonHeader.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) 
    && value.Value.Equals(jsonHeader.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

...is just a shorter variant for this...

```
bool ExistingHeaders(INameValue value)
{
    return value.Name.Equals(jsonHeader.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) 
        && value.Value.Equals(jsonHeader.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies it for me. I am getting a "cannot specify constructor arguments in declaration" error on that line. Can you suggest how this can be resolved?

Comment: @Blazanor The error and how it can be solved is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1528

Answer (score 1):

INameValue value is a parameter for the method named ExistingHeaders. By using the interface as the parameter type, it is allowing any object that has implemented INameValue to be passed in as a parameter.

The parameter was initialized before being passed into the method. The method is not instantiating anything. It is just doing a string comparison on the properties Name and Value in the object passed in as a parameter.